# Shortest sequence of moves

Tags: artificial-intelligence, path-finding, maze

Disclaimer: this problem came from my past AI final exam. And I found it very interesting but I couldn't figure it out.

There is the description:
Given a maze you are free to move between adjacent white cells, but black cells are blocked. You can try to move UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT. If you are not blocked in that direction, you successfully move. If you are blocked, you stay in the same place.

a) Find the shortest possible sequence of moves that guarantee you will end up at G regardless of where you started.

[image: grid]

Comment: I would say BFS, vary similar to a*

Comment: Can you provide more details?

Comment: Do you know the color of next cells before making a move? Is there a penalty for trying? Either way, it should be backtracking. Or dynamic programming if you want to be hip :)

Comment: Yes, you can detect your surrounding cells and there is no penalty for trying. Can you elaborate your ideas? First, we need to prove that there exists a sequence of moves that guarantee that any valid start point would end up in G by performing these moves.  Second, we need to find these moves and minimize the number of these moves.

Comment: This is a good question. People shouldn't close-vote just because they can't figure out an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Before making any moves, you may be in any position.   After each move, your set of possible positions will shift, and may shrink when moving from some possible positions would hit a wall.  The set of possible positions will never increase in size, though.

You may assume a directed graph, with a vertex for each set of positions that may arise, and an edge connecting each set to the 4 sets that would follow from moving left, right, up, or down.

Your task, then, is to find the shortest path from the vertex for the set of all positions to the vertex for the singleton set containing only the target position.

My first attempt would by to run A* on this graph using an appropriate metric.  The number of possible sets is extremely large, though, so this is not guaranteed to be feasible.  I would use my human intelligence to try to pick a metric that works quickly.

If you can choose a metric that gets A* to completion in a reasonable amount of time, and conforms to the rules that A* puts on metrics, then that will prove that the path you found is the shortest one.

Off the top of my head, I would first try the length of the shortest path to the target from the furthest position in the set.  Maybe in combination with the total number of non-empty rows and columns.

So this is what I would do, but I am not an AI expert.  I am guessing that there is probably something you learned in class that can improve upon this procedure.